# Why i can not get the update value in an AngularJs factory?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

I am trying to update and then get the update value of an AngularJs factory, I am setting the value in one scope and trying to get it in another, I am setting a factory to handle the pop up messages in my app so instead of repeating my self I want just one factory to handle the messages.

```
myApp.factory('msg',function ($modal) {
    factory = {};

    factory.text = '';
    factory.modal;
    factory.response;

    factory.window = function () {
        this.modal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl:'partials/message/confirm.html',
            controller:'cms'
        });
    }

    factory.setText = function (text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    factory.getResponse = function () {
        return this.response;
    }

    factory.confirm = function () {
        this.modal.close();
        this.response = true;
    }

    factory.cancel = function () {
        this.modal.close();
        this.response = false;
    }

    factory.confirmSave = function () {
        this.text = 'save';
        this.window();
    }

    factory.confirmUpdate = function () {
        this.text = 'update';
        this.window();
    }

    factory.confirmDelete = function () {
        this.text = 'delete';
        this.window();
    }


    return factory;
});
```

the users controller

```
myApp.controller('users',function ($scope,$location,$http,msg) {
    $http.get('api/v1/users')
    .success(function (data,status) {
        $scope.user = data;
    })
    .error(function (data,status) {
        $location.path('/login');
    });

    $scope.showWrite = function () {
        $scope.write = true;
    }

    $scope.closeWrite = function () {
        $scope.write = false;
        $scope.newUser = '';
    }

    $scope.save = function () {
        $http.post('api/v1/users/store',$scope.newUser)
        .success(function (data,status) {

            $scope.user.unshift({
                first_name: $scope.newUser.first_name,
                last_name: $scope.newUser.last_name,
                email: $scope.newUser.email,
                role: $scope.newUser.role
            });

            $scope.write = false;
            $scope.newUser = '';
        })
        .error(function (data,status) {
            alert('failed');
        });
    }

    $scope.confirmDelete = function (index,id) {
        msg.confirmDelete();
        if(msg.getResponse() === true){
            $http.get('api/v1/users/destroy/'+id)
            .success(function (data,status) {
                $scope.user.splice(index,1);
            })
            .error(function (data,status) {
                alert('failed');
            });
        };
        console.log(msg.getResponse());
    }

    $scope.showUserInfo = function () {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code you provided working fine and the problem is somewhere else, probably in `cms` controller or in `confirm.html` template. I've made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u98nxn1gZIDcXwnfPezG?p=preview) with your factory where you can see it live.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
  <button ng-click="msg.confirmSave()">confirm save</button>
  <span ng-if="msg.getResponse() !== undefined">Response: {{msg.getResponse()}}</span>
</div>
```

**confirm.html**

```
<h1>{{msg.text}}</h1>
<button ng-click="msg.confirm()">Confirm</button>
<button ng-click="msg.cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap']).
  controller('cms', ['$scope', 'msg', function($scope, msg){
    $scope.msg = msg;
  }]).
  controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'msg', function($scope, msg) {
    $scope.msg = msg;
  }]).
  factory('msg',['$modal', function ($modal) {
    // The same code as in the question
  }]);
```

*Some tips:*

- Use `var factory = {};` instead of `factory = {}` in order to declare local variable and not to override global `factory` occasionally.
- `factory.modal;` and `factory.response;` do not declare relevant properties in `factory` object as you expect, but return `undefined` instead, so just remove them, because they are useless
- `factory.setText` and `facory.getResponse` are redundant, since `factory.text` and `factory.response` are public properties of `factory`. If you want to make them private to the factory, declare them as `var text;` and `var response;` and change the accessor methods accordingly. It will be also useful to add`getText` to your factory in that case.
- If you plan to access `factory.modal` only from you factory, it is better to incapsulate it to your factory (make it private) as described in the previous bullet.
- Expose only public API from the factory (don't expose `window` for example)

After applying all tips your factory may look like the following:

```
factory('msg',['$modal', function ($modal) {
    var text = '',
        modal,
        response;

    function window () {
        modal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl:'confirm.html',
            controller:'cms'
        });
    }

    return {
      setText: function (_text_) {
        text = _text_;
      },
      getText: function() {
        return text;
      },
      getResponse: function () {
        return response;
      },
      confirm: function () {
        modal.close();
        response = true;
      },
      cancel: function () {
        modal.close();
        response = false;
      },
      confirmSave: function () {
        text = 'save';
        window();
      },
      confirmUpdate: function () {
        text = 'update';
        window();
      },
      confirmDelete: function () {
        text = 'delete';
        window();
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4o6VPaMY6JRpmF4Bpi3?p=preview).

***EDIT:***

After you updated the post with controller code everything is clear to me: the real problem is that you use `confirmDelete()` synchronously, but it is asynchronous (since returns value in the future, once user clicks confirm or cancel)! To deal with asynch staff angular has a [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) service. In order to use it, you should create deferred object in `factory.confirmSave()`, `factory.confirmUpdate()` and `factory.confirmDelete()`, return it's promise and resolve/reject it in `factory.confirm()` and `factory.cancel()`. Once promise is resolved or rejected you can fetch the value from `factory` or get it directly as argument of relevant callback.

**factory**

```
function confirmDelete() {
  deferred = $q.defer();
  text = this;
  window();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

**controller**

```
msg.confirmDelete().then(function(value) {
    // Resolved
    $scope.response = value;
}, function(value) {
    // Rejected
    $scope.response = value;
});
```

Full example see in the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJiyFNJsSe2dWAsp2YWo?p=preview).

Comment: it works fine here as well but as you said looks like the problem is in other controllers,i am using anngularjs+foundatio and for that i am using http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/ modal directive , the "cms" controller is there to just show the modal content , i am calling the 'msg' factory and inject it in another controller and tries to act upon the response , so when the user confirms , the 'msg' factory 'response' property get updated to be 'true', the problem is that i can only get the correct respond on the second click! , check the updated code

Comment: @munzx See my last edit. I think I found the root cause of the issue.

Comment: thanks man , that was really pretty helpful!!! , you are awesome , thanks again :)

Comment: i would appreciate it if you can help me with this as well!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213596/how-to-pass-data-to-an-angular-foundation-modal-scope        thanks again :)